# generators for a graded algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, filtered-algebras

I have a graded commutative algebra over a field $K$ and I also know that it is not generated by the degree 1 elements. Somehow I could guess a set of generators, is there a criterion to check that this set generates the graded algebra without considering each and every polynomial of a graded piece ?

Comment: There might be a way, but that depends on further information you have on the algebra, e.g. the dimension of every graded component. If you can write your algebra as (finitely generated) matrix ring modulo ideal you might be able to use Groebner bases. I'm not sure if there is a general approach that always allows for nice checks, but it is surely possible in certain cases.